# How to count different nationalities for an employee without Row_Number()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this following query to get different nationalities for an employee:

```
SELECT 
    an.EmployeeId,c.CountryId, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY an.EmployeeId ORDER BY an.EmployeeId) AS rn
FROM 
    Nationality an
JOIN 
    country c ON an.CountryId = c.id
```

Which returns the following result:

```
EmployeeId CountryId rn
-----------------------
45          1        1
45         26        2
33         45        1
66         90        1
```

My expected output is like below, I want it without `row_number()`:

```
EmployeeId Count 
----------------
45         2         
33         1        
66         1
```

Comment: What's the relation between these two tables?

Comment: I want to count how many nationalities has each employee.

Comment: Have you had a look at the aptly named function [`COUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Why the INNER JOIN then? Simpy write SELECT EmployeeId, Count(CountryId) FROM Nationality GROUP BY EmployeeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to join with the country table

You can simply use the below query.

```
select EmployeeId, Count(CountryID) 
From Nationality 
Group By EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like below :

```
 SELECT an.EmployeeId ,count(c.ID) AS nationalitycount
    FROM AF_Nationality an
    JOIN country c ON an.CountryId = c.id
    GROUP BY an.EmployeeId
```

Comment: The join is redundant, you could get the same results without the join if you use `COUNT(an.CountryId)` instead.